# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport.<init>(Lcom/google/api/client/http/javanet/ConnectionFactory;

Tags: java

Good morning. My program wants to communicate with my google drive account. So I took example to see how I can do it. But I have the same error still now. Please help me.

The problem is on this line :

```
NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

When I'm execute I have this error:

> com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport.(Lcom/google/api/client/http/javanet/ConnectionFactory;Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)

My source code:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DriveQuickstart {

static final String oz = org.apache.http.conn.ssl .SSLConnectionSocketFactory.class.getProtectionDomain (). getCodeSource(). getLocation (). getPath ();


private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "DriveQuickstart";

private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

// Directory to store user credentials for this application.
private static final java.io.File CREDENTIALS_FOLDER //
        = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "credentials");

private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_FILE_NAME = "client_secret.json";

//
// Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart. If modifying these
// scopes, delete your previously saved credentials/ folder.
//
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {

    java.io.File clientSecretFilePath = new java.io.File(CREDENTIALS_FOLDER, CLIENT_SECRET_FILE_NAME);

    if (!clientSecretFilePath.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Please copy " + CLIENT_SECRET_FILE_NAME //
                + " to folder: " + CREDENTIALS_FOLDER.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(clientSecretFilePath);

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
            clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(CREDENTIALS_FOLDER))
                    .setAccessType("offline").build();

    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    System.out.println("voici le path "+oz);

    System.out.println("CREDENTIALS_FOLDER: " + CREDENTIALS_FOLDER.getAbsolutePath());

    // 1: Create CREDENTIALS_FOLDER
    if (!CREDENTIALS_FOLDER.exists()) {
        CREDENTIALS_FOLDER.mkdirs();

        System.out.println("Created Folder: " + CREDENTIALS_FOLDER.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Copy file " + CLIENT_SECRET_FILE_NAME + " into folder above.. and rerun this class!!");
        return;
    }

    // 2: Build a new authorized API client service.
    NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();






    // 3: Read client_secret.json file & create Credential object.
    Credential credential = getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT);

    // 5: Create Google Drive Service.
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential) //
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

    // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
    FileList result = service.files().list().setPageSize(10).setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute();
    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No files found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Files:");
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: show your pom.xml or dependencies version

Comment: pls add the required jar in lib folder

Comment: i don't have a pom.xml, i don't use marven. I've add all required jar in my lib folder. Please, what are you talking about?? I need Help please

Comment: @shihabudheenk please which jar are you talking about??

Answer (score 1):

This is a jar dependency issue. Update your question with a screenshot of libs folder.

In order to work this please add the below jars in lib if not exists already

```
google-oauth-client-1.30.5.jar
google-oauth-client-java6-1.30.6.jar
google-oauth-client-jetty-1.30.6.jar
google-api-client-1.30.9.jar
google-http-client-1.34.0.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.34.2.jar
google-api-services-drive-v3-rev195-1.25.0.jar
httpclient-4.5.12.jar
```

Also, add the below lines of code just above where the exception is occurring to see from which jar they are referenced in

```
System.out.println(NetHttpTransport.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
System.out.println(GoogleNetHttpTransport.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

Comment: i've added the lines; And this is the result:                                                           /C:/Users/NGONO/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SAMAC/google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar
/C:/Users/NGONO/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SAMAC/google-api-client-1.30.9.jar

Comment: all the jar have being added

Comment: Well I added the jars mentioned in my post and it executed without exception. I had the 1.34.0 version of google-http-client jar. Try that and remove 1.11.0-beta

Answer (score 0):

use your class package while calling the class

```html
HttpTransport httpTransport = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
```

I hope it will work